# How do I pass command line parameters to executables run from Xwindows?

Tags: 12.04, command-line

Running Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS

In terminal mode executable would be run as:

```
../xpdp1 -i ../inp/maxwello.inp
```

Is there a way I can click on the xpdp1 executable in Xwindows and somehow pass the `-i ../inp/maxwello.inp` to it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Not directly, no. You'd need to [make a launcher](https://askubuntu.com/questions/13758/how-can-i-edit-create-new-launcher-items-in-unity-by-hand) (there are other guides too). You could either hard-code the path in or you could use something like `zenity`:

```
sh -c '../xpdp1 $(zenity --file-selection)'
```